# Creating a view that combines permissiongroups together to show which permissions a user has

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a quistion regarding making a view.

I have 3 tables

users:

- id
- name
- email
- password

permissiongroups:

- id
- name
- viewUsers (tiny int, 1 or 0)
- updateUsers (tiny int, 1 or 0)
- createUsers (tiny int, 1 or 0)
- deleteUsers (tiny int, 1 or 0)
- (many other perms) (tiny int, 1 or 0)

user_has_permissiongroups:

- id
- userId
- permissiongroupId
- userIdCreator
- active

Now what I want is to make a single view that shows what permissions a user has. Say they have a group that can delete users (and all else as 0 (or false)), and another group that can create them (and all else as 0 (or false)), I want a combined row that shows both being a 1 (true) and everything else 0 (false).

Now what I need help with is the creation of the select statement as I have no idea where to begin. I will need to make something that groups by user.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_has_permissiongroups
LEFT JOIN permissiongroups
ON user_has_permissiongroups.permissiongroupId = permissiongroups.id
WHERE user_has_permissiongroups.active = 1
GROUP BY userId
```

Now this gets me almost where I need to be, but it doesn't group the permissions together correctly yet. Does anyone know how I can best do this? Or is this not possible within sql, meaning I have to keep it in the software?

**Desired output:**

| userId | viewUsers | updateUsers | createUsers | deleteUsers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

With tables:
permissiongroups:

| id | name | viewUsers | updateUsers | createUsers | deleteUsers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | test2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | test3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

user_has_permissiongroups:

| id | userId | permissiongroupId | userIdCreator | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3(not relevant) | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3(not relevant) | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 3(not relevant) | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 3(not relevant) | 1 |

Please note that there are many more permissions, it would be best if it were possible that it automatically takes all of them.

Regards
Dany

Comment: Do you want each permission in a different column? That means you need a pivot. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You're using `GROUP BY` without any aggregation fucntion. So you'll just get one row for each user, with permission data from a random row in the group. You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine the permissions into a single column.

Comment: Please add sample data and the desired result.

Comment: I indeed want every permission in a different column. I have added some sample data and result.